# c program will not read user input

Tags: c, user-input, scanf

I am writing a client/server and after I am done getting information from the clients they close. Now I am trying to ask the user (server side) if they would like to continue but my program jumps straight to the end of the program.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


main (void)
{
  int to_server;    // to read from client
  int from_server;  // to write to client
  int finish;   // lets me know that client is done
  int i,j,k,m,l,p;  // because C needs this defined as int
  int numClient;// number of clients
  char temp[14];
  int page_size = 128;
  int pages_left;
  int max_frames=10;
  int used_frames = 0;
  int frameUpdate=0;
  int freeframe[10] = {3,0,9,8,7,5,1,4,2,6};
  int numpage=0;
  int frames;
  int client1[5];
  int client2[5];
  int client3[5];
  int check;
  int option;
  int byte;
  int search;
  int getPage;
  int getOffset;
  int physical_Addr;
  int offset;
  int req[3];
  int dummy = 0;
  int again;


  struct values{
      char privFifo[14];
      int memoryreq;
  }cinput;


  /* Create the fifos and open them  */
  if ((mkfifo("FIFO1",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
    {
    perror("cant create FIFO1");
    exit(-1);
    }
  if((to_server=open("FIFO1", O_RDONLY))<0){
       printf("cant open fifo to write");
  }

  //get number of clients
  printf("\nHow many clients?\n");
  scanf("%d", &numClient);

  for(j =1; j <= numClient; j++){
      read(to_server, &cinput, sizeof(cinput));
      printf("\n\nFifo_%d \nMemory request %d", cinput.privFifo, cinput.memoryreq);
      req[j-1] = cinput.memoryreq;
      if(cinput.memoryreq > 1280){
          printf("\nERROR! Insufficient memory for request!");
          exit(-1);
      }
        if((mkfifo(cinput.privFifo,0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
           {
            perror("cant create privFifo");
            exit(-1);
          }

        if((from_server=open(cinput.privFifo, O_WRONLY)<0)){
              printf("cant open fifo to write");
      }

      // find number of pages need for request
      numpage = cinput.memoryreq/page_size;

      if((numpage * page_size) < cinput.memoryreq){
          numpage++;
      }

      sleep(1);
      printf("\nPages needed %d", numpage);
      write(from_server, &numpage, sizeof(numpage));

      printf("\n******Main Memory******");
      for(m = 0; m < numpage; m++){
          if(j==1){
          printf("\n* client: %d\tframe: %d", j, freeframe[m]);
          frames = freeframe[m];
          client1[m] = frames;
         // write(from_server, &frames, sizeof(frames));
          used_frames++;
          }
          else if (j == 2){
              printf("\n* client: %d\tframe: %d", j, freeframe[dummy]);
              frames = freeframe[dummy];
              write(from_server, &frames, sizeof(frames));
              used_frames++;
              dummy++;
          }
          else if (j == 3){
              printf("\n* client: %d\tframe: %d", j, freeframe[dummy]);
              frames = freeframe[dummy];
              write(from_server, &frames, sizeof(frames));
              used_frames++;
              dummy++;
          }
      }

      dummy = used_frames;
      used_frames = max_frames - used_frames;

      if(j==1){
          pages_left = max_frames - numpage;
      }
      else {
          pages_left = dummy;
      }

      printf("\n Frames available:");
      for(l = pages_left; l!= 0; l--){
            check = max_frames - l;
            printf(" %d", freeframe[check]);
        }
        pages_left = check;
      close(from_server);
      unlink(cinput.privFifo); 
  }

  printf("\nDONE!!!"); 


  close(to_server);
  unlink("FIFO1");
}
```

Here is my problem area (sorry for my messy code ):

```
  printf("press 1 to find Physical address of a byte?");
  scanf("%d\n", &again);
  while(again == 1){
   printf("\nWhich client are we accessing? ");
      scanf("%d", &option);
      printf("\nWhat byte would you like to find? ");
      scanf("%d", &byte);
      if(option == 1){
          for(p = 0; p < sizeof(client1); p++){
              search = p*page_size;
              if(search <= byte)
                 getPage= client1[p];
          }
          getOffset=byte%page_size;
          physical_Addr = (getPage * page_size) + offset;
          printf("Physical Address is %d", physical_Addr);
      }
      else if(option == 2){
          for(p = 0; p < sizeof(client1); p++){
              search = p*page_size;
              if(search <= byte)
                 getPage= client1[p];
          }
          getOffset=byte%page_size;
          physical_Addr = (getPage * page_size) + offset;
          printf("Physical Address is %d", physical_Addr);

      }
      else if(option == 3){
          for(p = 0; p < sizeof(client1); p++){
              search = p*page_size;
              if(search <= byte)
                 getPage= client1[p];
          }
          getOffset=byte%page_size;
          physical_Addr = (getPage * page_size) + offset;
          printf("Physical Address is %d", physical_Addr);

      }

      else{
          printf("ERROR!");
      }

      printf("Press 1 to choose another client.");
      scanf("%d", &again);
  }
```

Comment: Please separate the problem area from the rest of the "noisy" code.

Comment: yeah sorry I didn't take that into consideration.

Comment: why scanf("%d\n", &again);  , can we put scanf("%d", &again);

Comment: It was originally scanf("%d", &again);  but it gave me the same result. I read that scanf reads a newline buffer and a way to counteract that was to  either add a space eg scanf(" %d", &again); or to add a \n to get rid of it. Either way results in the same thing. My code just jumps in the end though it does read my prompts.

Comment: Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
  When we can't see the code for the variable declarations, the chances are very high (99.999%) that you have not created an MCVE.

Comment: Note that `\n` at the end of an interactive `scanf()` is a devastatingly awful way to treat your users.  The input does not terminate until the user types something other than a blank, tab or newline.  Further, that character will be the first byte of the next input stream.  The rule is simple: do not put white space at the end of a `scanf()` format stream.  However, it isn't clear that your problem is caused by this.  The code only reads integers AFAICS, and that automatically skips white space, so you don't have to fret about it.  (What you read applies to `%c` and `%[…]` — aka scan sets.)